# Cannot find the declaration of element 'xs:schema'

Tags: xml, xsd

My XML(1st statement):

```
<ReportConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

............

MY XSD(First few lines):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="ReportConfig">
```

........

but, I am getting following error
XML Document has Error:true cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xs:schema'.

Answer (score 1):

It's my mistake.

I was validating XSD instead of XML. I changed this and it worked fine.

Thank you!